# C++ Time Taken in Map Access and Iteration

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, operators

I was profiling code using gprof and I observed that -> operator of consuming a significant amount of time.

This is sample definition of map.

```
map<int, vector<int> > myMap;
```

I have an iterator,

```
map<int, vector<int> >::iterator it;
```

I frequently run loops like:

```
for(it = myMap.begin(), it != myMap.end(); it++) {
   //Do stuff
}
```

This is the data from profiling

```
Function:
std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::vector<ClassType*, std::allocator<ClassType*> > > >::operator->() const
Time Consumed:
20.18%
Number of Times function is called:
15285739415

Function:
std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::vector<ClassType*, std::allocator<ClassType*> > > >::operator++(int)
Time Consumed:
2.90%
Number of Times function is called:
3825378111
```

From my understanding, ++ operator calculates next element which taken `O(log(n))` and -> gives the element which should take `O(1)` time. 
Even though -> operator is called more than ++ operator, I think it should not consume that amount of time.
Shouldn't `++` consume more time than `->` operator?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations? Profiling without optimizations it not representative at all.

Comment: Also notice that operator-> is called 4 times more often then operator++. Is this intended? Moreover, the standard requires all the operation on iterators to be amortized contant time ([iterator.requirements.general] P8). Thus increment is also O(1)

Comment: I am compiling without optimizations. I will try compiling with optimizations. -> is called more than ++ since I access memory more often. If ++ is O(1), then which operator calculates the next node? Looking at the function calls of ->, I dont think -> calculates the next node.

Comment: `++` finds the next node. But it does so without traversing the tree again (it only has to go up and then down to the next child). This gives amortized constant time.

Comment: Oh! Alright. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory access (`->` operator) is generally much slower than arithmetic operations (`++` operator).

This is due to the fact that it takes time to search for the data, starting from the cache on the lowest level (closest to the registers) all the way to possibly pages in the hard disk drive. As you may expect, this takes a fair amount of time the further you get away from the registers.

Arithmetic operations, however, may not need to involve memory access. If the data involved in the arithmetic operation can fit into the registers, there would not be a need to access even the cache on the lowest level.

Here's a [good article](http://supercomputingblog.com/optimization/taking-advantage-of-cache-coherence-in-your-programs/) on how cache coherence/spatial locality can affect the speed of your application.